# About validity of a marriage due to swear by the name of child

Tags: nikah, fiqh, oaths

I have given divorce to my husband. and I made promise on my child for not doing 2nd marriage.Is there any procedure to break this promise

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, the woman doesn't have the **sole** right of divorce. She can 'request' a divorce, and then it's either up to the husband to declare the divorce, or a judge to make a decision. No divorce is in place on a woman's words, alone.

The second issue is that there is no (proper) swearing in Islam except by Allah. Any swear done on anything else is not really valid.

Divorce can get complicated at times, and should be asked properly from a scholar in person to discuss all that concerns your particular case. Asking it here will probably give you an idea of the solution, but you shouldn't act on an answer here.

But to answer your question, in the worst case scenario, you'll need to give the Kaffarah of breaking a promise by making a second marriage. I'm not exactly sure what the Kaffarah would be, but I think an option is to fast three days in return. Simple!

Comment: Islam does give right to divorce to women it is called Khulah and it is widely practiced.

Comment: is it the practice when at the time of marriage the man agrees to give the right to his wife? If so can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khula there are schools where husbands permission is not required but a permission only from the Islamic authority is required

Comment: that's no different to what I said then: "She can only 'request' a divorce, and then it's either up to the husband to declare the divorce, or a judge to make a decision. No divorce is in place on a woman's words, alone."

Comment: in other words, it comes back to the decision by judicial authorities or the husband if the woman agrees to pay compensation. but, for example, by just saying "you're now divorced from me" the woman can't divorce the husband.

Comment: Husband can be bypassed by an Islamic authority very easily , So practically she can initiate divorce

Comment: Two questions: Can the husband divorce the wife by himself, without the consent of an authority? Yes. Can the wife do that? No. That's all I'm trying to say.

Comment: By the way, don't get me wrong and think that I'm trying to argue or find something wrong in it. I'm totally with this law and I understand that whatever Islam rules, it's certainly for the benefit of both sides! No need to get into justifications of why a wife can't divorce her husband on her own.. etc.

Comment: Ya you are correct